# How Jump automatically to another report according to a value. Reporting Services

Tags: reporting-services

Reporting Services

I need to jump to a specific report according to the value that takes a variable data set.

For example: If the variable has the value = 2, then go to the report 'Informe_1' but if the value is = 4, then go to the report 'Informe_2', this automatically without having to click anything. That is a generic type of report which determines which of the 2 reports must be charged according to the value of the variable.

Currently I have in the properties of the variable, in action, go to report, but I need to specify the condition to be 'Informe_1' or 'Informe_2' according to the value of that variable (2 or 4).

Comment: reporting-services and crystal-reports are not the same thing. Which is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of a way to automatically go to a specific report without the user clicking something; however, you can specify an expression for the Action on something and that way the user will get the report specified by your variable when they do click.

1. In Design view, right-click the text box, image, or chart to which you want to add a link and then click Properties.
2. In the item's Properties dialog box, click Action.
3. Select Go to report. Additional sections appear in the dialog box for this option.
4. In Specify a report, click Browse to locate the report that you want to jump to, or type the name of the report. Alternatively, click the expression (fx) button to create an expression for the report name.

Also, see [Expression Examples (Report Builder 3.0 and SSRS)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157328.aspx) for more information about expressions.

You can also alter the visibility of a linked item similarly. To give an example, in some of my own reports I have a hidden @ReportParameter that I use to pass the report to return to when a Back link is clicked. If that parameter is empty I hide the link. I use Go to report and specify `=Parameters!ParentReport.Value` in the expression for the Action. For Visibilty with show or hide based on an expression selected, visible is false and hidden is true. That makes my Visibility expression `=Parameters!ParentReport.Value = ""`.

Comment: mmm, I'm thinking of another solution, according to the value of the variable, show or hide the link to the corresponding report ... Do you think?

Comment: That would certainly work and is something I have done before. I use it to hide "Back" links in my reports when they have been visited directly instead of from another report.

Comment: Which expression or function would use to show or hide the links according to the value?

Comment: Updated my answer with an example from my own reports.